# sql - selecting, counting and Updating

Tags: sql, select, count, sql-update

I'm wondering if this is correct...

I want to select all users from teams in a match and then add a win, loose or draw to his profile.

```
$short = $_POST['short'];
$opponent = $_POST['opponent'];
$oppuser = safe_query("SELECT userID FROM ".PREFIX."teams_members WHERE teamID='".$opponent."'");
$shortuser = safe_query("SELECT userID FROM ".PREFIX."teams_members WHERE teamID='".$short."'");

safe_query("UPDATE ".PREFIX."teams_members SET win=win+1 WHERE userID='".$oppuser."'");
safe_query("UPDATE ".PREFIX."teams_members SET lost=lost+1 WHERE userID='".$shortuser."'");
```

Something is not allowing updating the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need those selects. Your update is not working because the select statement is returning you multiple entries. You can update the entire team without selecting the users:

```
$short    = $_POST['short'];
$opponent = $_POST['opponent'];

safe_query("UPDATE ".PREFIX."teams_members SET win=win+1 WHERE teamID='$opponent'");
safe_query("UPDATE ".PREFIX."teams_members SET lost=lost+1 WHERE teamID='$short'");
```